# Is there a way to easily make SIGINT events silent without making them disappear?

Tags: ruby, bash

I often use a method like this in my ruby code:

```
def register_sigint
  Signal.trap('SIGINT') { exit }
end
```

When I hit ctr + c then the program usually exits instantly.

Now here is the thing:

In my main shell, bash, this displays a "^C"

On a new line.

Is there a way I can make it show nothing at all instead?

The reason why I want this:

I use ruby to ask me exam questions, and I pad the answers + colourize them.

Now when I hit ctrl + c to exit, I get these two characters, and the alignment gets messed up. This may seem minor, it probably is, but it simply annoys me because I have no need to read these two characters that I don't need.

For any help I'd be happy.

Here is a image showing the problem:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/OQV2xVe.png]

The orange-brown thing is Dir.pwd (current working directory)

The ^C appears before.

Answer (score 0):

The `^C` is displayed before Ruby captures the signal, and you cannot let it disappear from within Ruby without the use of a library that uses C code. But you can do

```
def register_sigint
  Signal.trap('SIGINT'){puts; exit}
end
```

to put the `^C` on a separate line before exiting.

Otherwise, you need to use the [curses](https://github.com/ruby/curses) library, or its variant to capture the key.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby isn't generating the `^C`; your shell is. Assuming your shell has the `stty` command (which is pretty likely unless you're on Windows), you can use `stty -ctlecho` to disable it.

To illustrate, here's a simple program that prints dots until it receives SIGINT, whereupon it prints "Bye!" and exits:

```
def setup!
  Signal.trap("INT") {
    shut_down!
    exit
  }
end

def shut_down!
  puts "Bye!"
end

setup!

loop do
  sleep 0.2
  print '.'
end
```

This is what we get if we run it for awhile and then press Ctrl+C:

```
$ ruby dots.rb
.......^CBye!
```

Not ideal.

Now let's modify the `setup!` and `shut_down!` methods to call `stty -ctlecho` and `stty ctlecho` to disable and reenable the printing of control characters, respectively:

```
def setup!
  system "stty -ctlecho"

  Signal.trap("INT") {
    shut_down!
    exit
  }
end

def shut_down!
  system "stty ctlecho"
  puts "Bye!"
end
```

Then:

```
$ ruby dots.rb
.......Bye!
```

If it seems weird to you to shell out to `stty` to modify the shell's behavior, I definitely understand, but in fact even core Ruby modules do the same thing, [for example RubyGems](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/a21d403f21473b21b5766c2483b4325240e9edda/lib/rubygems/user_interaction.rb#L335-L341).

P.S. Another thing you could do is use ANSI escape sequences to back up the cursor two characters when you receive SIGINT, which will cause subsequent output to basically "overwrite" the `^C`. The escape sequence to move the cursor left is `\033[nD`, where `n` is the number of characters ([reference here](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x361.html)), so:

```
def shut_down!
  print "\033[2D"
  puts "Bye!"
end
```